# Using "No-Width Optional Break" by Ctrl+Space shortcut key changes the font

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2016

After Microsoft making last update on my PC 10 hours ago, When I'm typing my text in word 2016, after using any **Shortcut Key** in my text such as **"No-Width Optional Break"** with **Ctrl+Space** Shortcut Key, my font will change to another font automatically. Why it happened?? How can I fix it?
I used **Reset All** and **Remove** buttons and assigned again a new shortcut key for that but it didn't work
(I have to use **"Shortcut Key"** for my work many times and fixing that problem is an emergency to me! please help me, Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

I finally did something that worked in my case. If you've had this problem with Arabic/Persian fonts, try these steps:

1. open MS Word and change your font to non Latin (Persian/Arabic)
2. On the **Insert** tab click on **Symbols**.
3. select a non Latin font (if it's not)
4. on **Character Code** box, type: **200C**
5. Assign your desired shortcut (shift+space worked for me)

It's all done. Hope it works for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

it seems "ctrl+space" by default clears all formatting styles including font, size etc. see the link below for a long list of shortcuts in MS word.

[Microsoft Word shortcut keys](http://www.computerhope.com/shortcut/word.htm)

Unfortunately, I couldn't find how to disable or remove this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled this in Word 2013 was to assign the no-width optional break character to a shortcut key that you won't frequently use, like alt-'.  THEN go into AutoCorrect and use the Alt-' key you just assigned to assign the no-width optional break to some other character sequence that is easy to type, such as ///.  So in File|Options, select Proofing, select the AutoCorrect tab, then in the Replace text as you type, put in /// on the left side and use the Alt-' shortcut to associate that sequence with the no-width optional break character.  Then click Assign.  Seems to work for me.  Every time I type three slash characters, it is replaced with the optional break (which you can see if you turn on paragraph marks).

Answer (score 0):

1.Uninstall current version of office
2.Install previous version of office
3.Assign No-Width Optional Break again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a long long time; its solution was really easy. 
Just go to Word Option>Customize Ribbon>Customize Keyboard
Select common symbols from left box and non-width optional beak from right one; allocate Ctrl+Space to it **once more**. By allocating the shortcut keys **again**, it will be removed from CharRest function